# I have an issue with my loops to show the result

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, mysqli

```
$array_of_time = array ();
$start_time    = strtotime ("$app_date 07:00");
$end_time      = strtotime ("$app_date 22:00");
$mins  = 04 * 60;

while ($start_time <= $end_time)
{
   $array_of_time[] = date ('h:i a', $start_time);
   $start_time += $mins;
}

echo "<div style='width:700px' class='time_slot_div'>";
echo "<p class='time_slot_p'> Time Slot :</p>";

foreach($array_of_time as $key=>$value)
{

    for($i = 0; $i < count($app_data); $i++)
    {
        $book_time=$app_data[$i]["appointment_time"];
        if($value==$book_time)
        {
           echo "<a  class='time_slot_a_book'>$value</a>&nbsp;";    
        } else {
           echo "<a href='#' onclick='get_time_value(\"$value\");' class='time_slot_a'>$value</a>&nbsp;";
        }
    }
}

echo "</div>";
```

Here foreach loop can run as many time as it can as well as for loop also, but i want to show the links that are not matched with the foreach value and for loop value.

The foreach loop values like 7:20 am not from database but the for loop value like 7:20 am is from database so if 7:20 am==7:20 am then the if statement it run it is working fine, but the issue is that it is running 2 time if i get 2 value in for loop. It should run my div only once.

Comment: did you try using break statement inside if?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, to be honest.

Comment: #vaibhavmande where should i use break statement?

Comment: #Amal i just want to get the result only one for this two loops. here foreach loop is showing all todays time slot for 07:00 am to 10:00 pm. with every 4 min gap and for loop is having values in between this two time suppose for loop is having 7:28 am then the result from foreach loop value of 7:28 am will not have anchor tag.

Comment: I think you should start using some commas.

Comment: Rafael why should i use commas, for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a array to store the item that has shown.

```
<?php

foreach($array_of_time as $key=>$value)
{
    $tag_list = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($app_data); $i++)
    {
        $book_time=$app_data[$i]["appointment_time"];

        // shown, skip
        if (isset($tag_list[$book_time]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // mark as show
        $tag_list[$book_time] = 1;

        if ($value == $book_time)
        {
            echo "<a  class='time_slot_a_book'>$value</a>&nbsp;";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a href='#' onclick='get_time_value(\"$value\");' class='time_slot_a'>$value</a>&nbsp;";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx srain but it is showing only 2 value that is 7:00 am 7:00 am that's it.

Comment: You only want the value `==` show only one time, and the other multiple times in for loop?

Comment: yes i want to show the == value in the if statement and the remaining are in else statement.

Comment: I updated the answer, it will skip when `$book_time` repeat. What about now?

Comment: 07:00 am 07:00 am 07:04 am 07:04 am 07:08 am 07:08 am 07:12 am 07:12 am 07:16 am 07:16 am 07:20 am 07:20 am 07:24 am 07:24 am 07:28 am 07:28 am 07:32 am 07:32 am 07:36 am 07:36 am 07:40 am 07:40 am 07:44 am 07:44 am 07:48 am 07:48 am 07:52 am 07:52 am 07:56 am 07:56 am 08:00 am 08:00 am 08:04 am 08:04 am 08:08 am 08:08 am 08:12 am 08:12 am 08:16 am 08:16 am 08:20 am 08:20 am 08:24 am 08:24 am 08:28 am 08:28 am 08:32 am 08:32 am 08:36 am 08:36 am 08:40 am 08:40 am 08:44 am 08:44 am 08:48

it still repeating the value :(